No module named 'django' when debugging inside vscode even though django is installed
I am trying to debug my django app inside docker container. I have specified following in my requirements file:
requirements.txt
Django==3.2.5
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
djangorestframework==3.12.4
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9.6-bullseye

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /my_project

COPY ./my_project/requirements.txt /my_project/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh

Also when I checked by attacking vscode to docker container and running pip, it shows that the django is indeed installed:
# pip list | grep Django
Django              3.2.5

However, still I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Here is the screenshot of error showing exception raised in debug mode, launch.json and output of pip list | grep Django:

PS: I am using docker compose to start the containers.

have you tried to use venv to manage you packages ?

I am already using docker, so did not tought of using venv inside docker ..

@Alifareeq Can you please explain why not using venv might be the issue, especially when I am already inside docker container. Also how I can do so when inside docker container? (also, I added dockerfile contents to the question)

VSCode installs its own installation of Python.  You can use commands to have it use the installation you want.

Can you reproduce the problem in a plain-Python virtual environment, without involving Docker at all?  Debugging things will probably be easier without adding an isolation system between yourself and the code you're working on.

Thanks to @TimRoberts for hint in the comment. I feel really do not need to create / select virtual environment inside docker. Docker itself is used to create sandboxed environment for all the dependencies. Creating sandbox inside sandbox does not make sense to me.
I was getting puzzled because I was getting same path for both python and python3:
# which python
/usr/local/bin/python

# which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

And it seems that pip and pip3 were corresponding to these installations:
# which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

# which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

But then I read Tim's comment and immediately started looking for more hint, and found one at the bottom right corner of the vscode:

Clicking on the python version on the vscode taskbar revealed another installaiton:

Earlier /usr/bin/python3 was selected. Dont know how this python got installed. But selecting /usr/local/bin/python made it work.
Btw, clicking on this button was the first thing that I used to do. But somehow this slipped my mind, may be over confidence that I have installed only one python in this docker environment and even which python and which python3 were showing same single python made me give soon.
